# What is the best strategy and location to complete the Controlled Fury achievement?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

The Controlled Fury achievement requires that you maintain max Fury for five minutes.

> **Controlled Fury**
>   Fight with maximum fury for 5 minutes.

What is the best strategy to get this achievement?  Is there a combination of abilities that makes it easier?  Is there a zone I should focus on? It seems like a long time to sit at max Fury.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Unforgiving passive skill would make this quite simple, regardless of where you fight. The skill unlocks at level 55 and does the following:

> You no longer degenerate Fury. Instead, you gain 1 Fury every 2 seconds.